# Behavior of redis.ConnectionPool with asyncio (redis-py)

Tags: redis, python-asyncio, fastapi, redis-py, keydb

I am using Redis in a FastAPI application using the [*redis-py*](https://github.com/redis/redis-py) library. I am unclear about the behavior of `redis.ConnectionPool` in this context, especially regarding how it handles situations where the number of connections exceeds the `max_connections` limit. I'm also seeking advice on whether I should create multiple clients using a single `ConnectionPool`, or to reuse a single client across the application.

Here's a example simple application:

```py
from redis.asyncio import ConnectionPool, Redis
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

pool = ConnectionPool(max_connections=10)
redis_shared = Redis(connection_pool=pool)

async def get_redis():
    return Redis(connection_pool=pool)
    # or alternatively
    #return redis_shared

@app.get("/")
async def my_route(redis: Redis = Depends(get_redis)):
    return await redis.get('mykey')
```

In this code, I'm not sure what happens when the number of concurrent tasks exceeds the `max_connections` (10) in the `ConnectionPool`. Does *redis-py* queue the excess connections, or will it raise an exception?

Additionally, is it more efficient or advisable to create multiple clients from a single `ConnectionPool`, or should I create and reuse a single client across my application?

Any insights or best practices regarding the use of `ConnectionPool` with asyncio in *redis-py* would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I stumbled upon [`BlockingConnectionPool`](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/70e2a1321019a4df873230ac64f11f1215198624/redis/connection.py#L1313-L1470) which partially answers the question about the behavior of the `ConnectionPool`.